# Windows Vista custom paper sizes

Tags: windows-vista, printing

Due to some circumstances I have to use a document that is of custom size.

I know that the printer supports this size, as I can set the custom paper size for the printer on an XP machine which has network access to the printer.

In XP i can set the custom size in Printer and Faxes section in the Control Panel under server properties (by defining a "form"). In Vista, there does not appear to be an equivalent.

Any ideas?

Comment: hmm, maybe I'm wrong, but how come you can print from the XP machine then? The results prints perfectly fine. The printer is an old dot matrix one - Epson LQ-570+. The drivers are default, as far as I can tell, I did not install them myself. I'll see tonight.

Comment: ok, found another idea. with the MS XPS document printer this might be possible.

Comment: OK, I found it and I am moving it to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I had a really hard time finding "Server Properties", which is where what you are looking for exists. In the screenshots I saw, it was in the left column, but I eventually just found it in the "File" menu. It looks to be the same as for XP.

So open `Control Panel>Printers`, hold the <kbd>ALT</kbd> key down to expose the menu if not visible, and click on `File>Server Properties`. From there, you can set your form as you always did.

[image]

Comment: thank you, the alt made the menu show. Also, if you choose from the menu, you cannot add any new forms. You should right-click and choose 'Run as Administrator' -> Server Properties. Please add this to your answer, if possible for future reference.

Comment: @sheepz True, to "Run as Administrator". I had UAC turned off on that computer.

Comment: I am having a problem. After setting a new form and clicking "Save Form", then clicking "OK", it works. However, whenever I restart my computer, every change I made, i.e. the new added form size is gone. I am running on Win 7 64 bit. This problem occurs only on dot matrix printers, I have no problem with laser printers.